# Magento 2.3 New Products are Not Display in their respective category pages

Tags: magento2, new-products

**Our new products are no longer showing on their respective category pages on the frontend.**

I have checked lots of items on the admin:

```
General->Status = Enabled
General->Visibility = Catalog,Search
Inventory->Qty > 0
Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock
Websites = assigned to website
Catgories = assigned to their respective categories.
```

Whereas new products are visible on the homepage in New Arrivals Block.

I have already run all the required commands as below:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chmod -R 777 pub/ var/ generated/
php bin/magento cron:run
```

I have also checked table in database `"inventory_stock_1"` and data is properly updated in this table as well.

Also checked below and there is no value as working:

```
update Magento.indexer_state set status='invalid' where status ='working'
```

**But still, the front end category view shows the only older products and not our newly uploaded products.**

Kindly help to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

please debug this file in this path - vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml , because this list.phtml file is responsible for the products on the category page i.e PLP (Product List page), add a breakpoint in line no 19, and start checking from there,  to see if the products are getting there.

Comment: Can you please help with how and what to add in breakpoint? Actually, I don't know how to debug.

Comment: That is a separate topic for a day , debugging skills are as much requirement as is developing , the most efficient way i'll recommend is by using xdebug.

Please read these links , this will help you how to set up xdebug and use it - 

https://magenest.com/en/debug-magento-2-code-xdebug-phpstorm-1/

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/howtos/debug.html

Before installing the xdebug , please note that latest version of xdebug is not supported by magento , so you need to install specific version of xdebug which is version - 2.9.8 using pecl which i will recommend.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.

I tried below code in this file: `app/design/frontend/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Comment: **Code Added top of file:**
`$objectManager= \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$categoryFactory=$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$category=$categoryFactory->create()->load(122);
$categoryProducts=$category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
echo "<h3>Product Count: ".$categoryProducts->count()."</h3>";
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) {echo "Name: ".$product->getName()."<br />"; }`

Above code is working fine & prints all product names but how can i implement this code & show all the products on my category pages?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands:

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush

if you are stilling having same problem let me know

Comment: Thank you for your help but I already tried this and still, the issue remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please check are you able to access product by this url

baseurl/catalog/product/view/id/product_id

if yes then its cache issue. And make sure you have assigned products to correct category and category is enabled and even products too.